# How to write a ~/.firefoxrc?

Tags: firefox, shell, firebug

I want firefox sources `~/.firefoxrc` automatically when I open a webpage.
`~/.firefoxrc` contains several javascript functions:

```
Array.prototype.sum = function(){
    for(var i=0,sum=0;i<this.length;sum+=this[i++]);
    return sum;
}
Array.prototype.max = function(){
    return Math.max.apply({},this)
}
Array.prototype.min = function(){
    return Math.min.apply({},this)
}
```

So I can use these functions in `firebug console`.

Answer (score 1):

Loading javascript code on startup of firefox can be done using [userChromeJS](http://userchromejs.mozdev.org/index.html).